React Component Workflow Issue: onComplete Function Undefined in Multi-Step Form Process
I'm working on a React application that involves a multi-step workflow process. The application manages various types of items, each with its own sequence of forms and actions.
The expected workflow is:
Display a list of items.
When an item is selected, open an initial form.
After completing the initial form, it should lead to a secondary form.
The secondary form should then lead to a series of additional steps and documents.
The current issue: The 'Complete' button in the initial form is not triggering the transition to the secondary form as expected. The console shows that the onComplete function is undefined when it's called.
Here are the relevant parts of my code:
Code that displays the the list of items:
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext, useCallback } from 'react';
import BaseLayout from '../components/BaseLayout';
import { fetchProperties } from '../services/api';
import PropertyCard from '../components/PropertyCard';
import AddPropertyButton from '../components/AddPropertyButton';
import ClientEngagement from '../components/ClientEngagement';
import PropertyInspection from '../components/PropertyInspection';
import { AuthContext } from '../contexts/AuthContext';
import '../styles/PropertyCard.css';
function CommercialPropertyListPage() {
const [properties, setProperties] = useState([]);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
const [error, setError] = useState(null);
const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState(null);
const [selectedProperty, setSelectedProperty] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
console.log('PropertyListPage mounted');
return () => {
console.log('PropertyListPage unmounted');
};
}, []);
const handleClientEngagementComplete = useCallback(() => {
console.log('PropertyListPage: handleClientEngagementComplete called');
setCurrentStep('inspection');
}, []);
useEffect(() => {
console.log('PropertyListPage: handleClientEngagementComplete defined:', handleClientEngagementComplete);
}, [handleClientEngagementComplete]);
const handlePropertyInspectionComplete = useCallback(() => {
console.log('PropertyListPage: handlePropertyInspectionComplete called');
setCurrentStep('offerLetter');
}, []);
useEffect(() => {
console.log('PropertyListPage: currentStep changed to', currentStep);
}, [currentStep]);
useEffect(() => {
const loadProperties = async () => {
setIsLoading(true);
try {
console.log('Current user:', currentUser);
if (!currentUser || !currentUser.token) {
throw new Error('No authentication token available');
}
const data = await fetchProperties('commercial', currentUser.token);
console.log('Fetched properties data:', data);
setProperties(data || []);
setError(null);
} catch (err) {
console.error('Failed to fetch properties:', err);
setError('Failed to load properties. Please try again later.');
setProperties([]);
} finally {
setIsLoading(false);
}
};
if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
loadProperties();
}
}, [currentUser]);
const handlePropertySelect = useCallback((property) => {
console.log('PropertyListPage: Property selected', property);
setSelectedProperty(property);
setCurrentStep(prevStep => {
console.log('PropertyListPage: Setting currentStep to engagement. Previous step:', prevStep);
return 'engagement';
});
}, []);
const handleCloseForm = useCallback(() => {
setCurrentStep(null);
setSelectedProperty(null);
}, []);
console.log('PropertyListPage: Rendering. CurrentStep:', currentStep);
console.log('PropertyListPage: Selected property:', selectedProperty);
if (isLoading) return Loading...;
if (error) return Error: {error};
return (
Commercial Properties
{properties.length > 0 ? (
properties.map(property => (
<PropertyCard
key={property._id}
property={property}
onSelect={() => handlePropertySelect(property)}
/>
))
) : (
No properties found. 
)}
{currentStep === 'engagement' && (
<ClientEngagement
key={selectedProperty?._id}
propertyId={selectedProperty?._id}
onClose={handleCloseForm}
onComplete={() => handleClientEngagementComplete()}
/>
)}
{currentStep === 'inspection' && (
<PropertyInspection
propertyId={selectedProperty?._id}
onClose={handleCloseForm}
onComplete={handlePropertyInspectionComplete}
/>
)}
);
}
export default CommercialPropertyListPage;
Initial form code:
// src/components/ClientEngagement.js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import '../styles/ClientEngagement.css';
const ClientEngagement = ({ propertyId, onClose, onComplete }) => {
const [clientName, setClientName] = useState('');
const [staffName, setStaffName] = useState('');
const [engagementDetails, setEngagementDetails] = useState('');
const [isFormValid, setIsFormValid] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
console.log('ClientEngagement mounted');
console.log('ClientEngagement: Initial props', { propertyId, onClose, onComplete });
return () => {
console.log('ClientEngagement unmounted');
};
}, [propertyId, onClose, onComplete]);
useEffect(() => {
setIsFormValid(clientName !== '' && staffName !== '' && engagementDetails !== '');
}, [clientName, staffName, engagementDetails]);
const handleSubmit = useCallback((e) => {
e.preventDefault();
console.log('ClientEngagement: Form submitted');
console.log('ClientEngagement: isFormValid:', isFormValid);
console.log('ClientEngagement: onComplete type:', typeof onComplete);
if (isFormValid) {
if (typeof onComplete === 'function') {
console.log('ClientEngagement: Calling onComplete function');
onComplete();
} else {
console.error('ClientEngagement: onComplete is not a function', onComplete);
}
}
}, [isFormValid, onComplete]);
console.log('ClientEngagement: Rendering, onComplete type:', typeof onComplete);
return (
×
Client Engagement
<input
type="text"
value={clientName}
onChange={(e) => setClientName(e.target.value)}
placeholder="Client Name"
required
/>
<input
type="text"
value={staffName}
onChange={(e) => setStaffName(e.target.value)}
placeholder="Staff Name"
required
/>
 setEngagementDetails(e.target.value)} 

placeholder="Engagement Details" 

required 

/> 

 

Complete Engagement 

 

 

    

   

 ); 

}; 

 

export default ClientEngagement; 

 

Console output:

ClientEngagement: Form submitted   

ClientEngagement: isFormValid: true   

ClientEngagement: onComplete type: undefined   

ClientEngagement: onComplete is not a function undefined   

I've tried debugging with console.logs, but I can't figure out why onComplete is undefined when it's called in the second component. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Thank you

I tried implementing a workflow where clicking the 'Complete Engagement' button in the Client Engagement form should transition to a Property Inspection form. I expected the onComplete function to be called and trigger this transition. However, the actual result was that onComplete was undefined when called, preventing the transition from occurring as intended. I added console.logs to track the function's type and execution, which revealed the undefined status of onComplete.

Your code base is not well structured making it difficult to understand. The onComplete function seems not to be passed correctly to the ClientEngagement component, which should be why it is showing as undefined. Try restructure your code so we understand better

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
